What happens when using the Ordon Sword where you place the second Sol in the Palace of Twilight?
What would happen if, when you are placing the second sol into the pedestal and the master sword is infused with light, you instead hold the Ordon Sword? I expect it to be the same but I'm curious if it's different or not.

How come it let me make tags that don't exist and Also didn't show up with the search tags thing? Can you see them? I'm on my tablet so I'm guessing that caused the problem cya it doesn't happen in my computer?

As you have 300+ Rep you can create new Tags, I will clean them up for you.

Please, refrain from creating useless tags. You can, but that doesn't mean you should. Btw I think that new tags will update each new day

Oh thx I didn't know!
